# Posicionar elemento a la derecha sin usar float

Tags: html, css

¿Habrá alguna manera de colocar este sidebar a la derecha sin usar float? Lo que pasa es que me desmaqueta otros elementos y además investigue que es una mala practica usarlo.

```css
#sidebar{
    width: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: orange;
    padding: 30px;
    border: orange;
}

.sidebar-item{
    background: #f7f7f7;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.sidebar-item h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin:0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #eee;
}

.sidebar-item .btn{
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn{
   display: block;
   background: black;
   color: white;
   padding: 15px; 
   font-weight: bold;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 14px;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: 300ms all;
   border: none;
   cursor:pointer;
   width: 50%;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-success{
    background: rgb(23, 150, 19);
}

.btn-success:hover{
    background:black;
}

input{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<aside id="sidebar">
    <div id="nav-blog" class="sidebar-item">
        <h3>Puedes hacer esto</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Crear artículo</a>
    </div>

    <div id="search" class="sidebar-item">
            <h3>Buscador</h3>
            <p>Encuentra el artículo que buscas</p>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="search" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn" />
            </form>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que no existe mas contexto de tu maquetación, es decir si este `aside` es hijo directo de `body` o de alguna otra etiqueta entonces te comentaré lo siguiente:

- La etiqueta `aside` debe estar contenida en otra mayor la cual es su padre
- A esa etiqueta que la contiene le daremos un `display: flex`;
- Por default todos los elementos con flex se alinean en el eje horizontal o *main axis* entonces le damos un `justify-content` con un valor de end para que se mueva al final de la fila

Quedando así:

```html
    <style>
      body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
      }
    #sidebar{
        width: 25%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        background: orange;
        padding: 30px;
        border: orange;
    }
    
    .sidebar-item{
        background: #f7f7f7;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .sidebar-item h3{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin:0px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #eee;
    }
    
    .sidebar-item .btn{
        margin: 0px auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .btn{
       display: block;
       background: black;
       color: white;
       padding: 15px; 
       font-weight: bold;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 14px;
       text-decoration: none;
       transition: 300ms all;
       border: none;
       cursor:pointer;
       width: 50%;
       text-align: center;
       font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .btn-success{
        background: rgb(23, 150, 19);
    }
    
    .btn-success:hover{
        background:black;
    }
    
    input{
    width:100%;
    }
    </style>
    
    <aside id="sidebar">
        <div id="nav-blog" class="sidebar-item">
            <h3>Puedes hacer esto</h3>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Crear artículo</a>
        </div>
    
        <div id="search" class="sidebar-item">
                <h3>Buscador</h3>
                <p>Encuentra el artículo que buscas</p>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="search" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn" />
                </form>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

> Por cierto no es una mala práctica usar una propiedad y valor que no estan *deprecated*, solo que hay que aprender en que escenarios convienen y en cuales no.

Comment: Con razón, la propiedad era flex-end y no end. El autocorrector me confundió jeje, gracias amigo @BetaM

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por las aclaraciones. Lo acabo de utilizar.